# Corporate iPhone but on personal wifi. What can my employer see? Can they see my browser history and website?

Tags: privacy

If an employee has a corporate iPhone but is on personal wifi. Can the employee view their browsing websites etc?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have a corporate phone. But I use it on my wifi and not through any VPN . The corporate phone has  google device policy installed. In such case would my employers be able to see my browser history( fire fox) or so?

Answer (score 3):

Your company probably use an MDM (Mobile device management) on your phone.

From [Apple website](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/resources/Managing_Devices_and_Corporate_Data_on_iOS.pdf) :

> Not all settings and account information are exposed. You can manage corporate
> accounts, settings, and information provisioned via MDM, but the user’s
> personal accounts cannot be accessed.

Here are some examples of what an MDM can/cannot see :

[image: Examples of what an MDM can and cannot see]

Keep in mind that if a VPN is turned on, your company can see what you are doing on your phone.

Edit : I didn't see your comment. Google Device Policy can see the exact same things. Here is a [detailed list](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/6098065).